# jquery коллаж как в vk, есть ли где-то такой плагин?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Штука следующая, есть очень много различных плагинов мозаек, коллажей для реализации вот такой штуки:

[image: коллаж]

Однако сегодня передо мной стала задача сделать следующее:
Нужно сделать вот такой коллаж, который бы не в зависимости от кол-во изображений вмещался в фиксированный блок.

Тоесть к примеру у нас есть блок width: 500px, height: 350px и в нем нужно разместить любое кол-во фото (до 10 штук), так что бы они всегда занимали всю область.

Перебрал уже кучу плагинов, но подобной конфигурации не встретил.  Если кто сталкивался, поделитесь пожалуйста.

Comment: четвертый пример [отсюда](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/08/30/automatic-image-montage/) не подходит?

Comment: К сожалению нет, любое кол-во изображений должно влазить в блок скажем 500 на 350 px, при этом всегда заполняя всю область без дыр. Скорее всего придется вспоминать математику и писать свой плагин.

Comment: А зачем плагин? Можно ведь все в CSS сделать. Минус только в том, что придется делать разные CSS для каждого варианта кол-ва картинок. Т.е. отдельный CSS если картинок 3, 4, 5 и т.д.

Answer (score 2):

Например, вот эта библиотека. http://creotiv.github.io/jquery-photowall/

Comment: Постарайтесь хотя бы в двух словах описывать, что скрывается за ссылкой. Если даёте ссылку на библиотеку, можно привести краткий пример и/или описать ключевые возможности. Если ссылка в будущем помрёт, то можно будет хотя бы зацепиться за текст.